# $z^5 - \overline{z^5}$ without using DeMoivre's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to give the Cartesian coordinate for $(1+2i)^5 + (1-2i)^5 = z^5 - \overline{z^5}$. Is there a simple way of giving the right answer without passing by the DeMoivre's theorem? Otherwise, how can I obtain the exact result in radians of $\tan^{-1}(2)$?

Comment: Note that this is real (why?).  You should be able to get a recursion for the numbers $a_n=(1+2i)^n+(1-2i)^n$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path There was an error in my question. I modified it.

Comment: You should edit posts to make them better, clearer etc, but not to change their meaning, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476). In particular, you should not modify questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. Fortunately, it is easy to submit another question! You can then post a link to it here, to draw additional attention to it :-)

Comment: @Michael Please do not change the question, especially after answers have been posted. Rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the left hand side of

$$
(1+2i)^5 + (1-2i)^5 = z^5-\overline{z}^5\tag1
$$

can be found by first computing $(1 + b)^5 + (1 - b)^5$ and then substituting $b=2i$. This way we obtain

$$
(1\pm b)^5 = 1 \pm 5b + 10 b^2 \pm 10 b^3 + 5 b^4 \pm b^5 \\
(1 + b)^5 + (1 - b)^5 = 2 + 20 b^2  + 10 b^4 \\
(1+2i)^5 + (1-2i)^5 = 2 - 80 + 160 = 82
$$

which is a real number. On the other hand, as @Saucy O'Path observed in the comments, the right hand side is imaginary. To see this, set $z^5 = a+ib$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ and note that $\overline{z}^5 = a-ib$. Therefore, $z^5 - \overline{z}^5 = 2ib$.

Thus, if $z=a+ib$ satisfies $(1)$ then $ib = 41$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. However, this is impossible. Therefore, there is no complex number $z$ that satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! There was an error in my question. I modified it.

Comment: I did not see your response when I posted my answer. I gladly vote for you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you! We seem to have written in parallel. Yours shows a similar calculation, +1, too.

Answer (score 3):

If I have

$$z-\overline{z}^5=(a+ib)^5-(a-ib)^5$$

and I develops the fifth power (without to use  DeMoivre's formula) I will have:
$$a^5+5ia^4b-10a^3b^2-10ia^2b^3+5ab^4+ib^5-(a^5-5ia^4b-10a^3b^2+10ia^2b^3+5ab^4-ib^5)$$
$$=a^5+5ia^4b-10a^3b^2-10ia^2b^3+5ab^4+ib^5-a^5+5ia^4b+10a^3b^2-10ia^2b^3-5ab^4+ib^5$$
$$=10ia^4b-20ia^2b^3+2ib^5=(10a^4b-20a^2b^3+2b^5)i \neq (1+2i)^5 + (1-2i)^5.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was an error in my question. I modified it